# Connecting router clients from LAN and WLAN on the Netgear WNDR3700

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, bridge

I have the Netgear WNDR3700 router, and I can't see computers that are are connected via WLAN from computers that are connected via LAN. Is there a way to set it up so they can see each other?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have AP isolation/client isolation (these are two different names for the same thing - I believe netgear uses AP Isolation as the term, but YMMV)  turned on - this a feature that seperates clients on wireless from those on a wired connection (and in some cases clients on different wireless bands from each other as well). I'm not sure of the exact location of this on your router's settings, but you may want to turn it off.

Comment: Good idea, but it turns out "Wireless Isolation" is off. I noticed the subnets are 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x - might that be the cause?

Comment: Yeah, it would possibly. Its unusual that it would do this, but being on seperate subnets might be the cause of the issue too.